# jQuery - Carousel installation problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcarousel

I have two plugins installed on my site, Jcarousel and a show and hide menu function, which can be found on the *About Us* button. I've noticed my Jcarousel functions disable when I enable the jQuery show and hide plugin. Is there a way I can prevent this, such as applying a CSS value in my JavaScript code?

The link `http://natesmithen.com/wired/test/test.html` demonstrates it.

Comment: You are loading JQuery twice. A local version and other off site version. Remove one of them to start with.

Comment: that's done, but i still can't figure out what's causing the issue

Comment: Move this line "<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>" from the <head> to just before the closing </body> and try again.

Comment: I've attempted that, still no joy

Comment: You haven't pasted it where I said. It needs to go after the 2 <script> blocks. Make it the last line of code before the </body>

Answer (score 0):

Use a console to check for script errors. As soon as page loads an error is thrown for a plugin call for plugin that doesn't exist

Comment: I know i'm getting an error from a mouseScroller i've installed$("#mcs_container").mCustomScrollbar("vertical",300,"easeOutCirc",1.05,"auto","yes","yes",15); But i'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with that??

Comment: "pretty sure" doesn't count. An error can cause all other script to not load

Comment: where's the carousel?, page has flash at top.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me so I'll post it as an answer..

Move this line from your `<head>`:

```
<script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to just before the closing `</body>`

**EDIT**:

Working site: [LINK](http://3rror404.com/test/wired-test.html)